# avoid same numbers and zero in array

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a form with that table:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzlorca/w3ugevt6/)

In this form i need to enable to edit the number fields.
After submit i collect the data and write to mysql.

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST['number'] as $key => $val) 
{
    $number                 = $_POST['number'][$key];
    $name                   = $_POST['name'][$key];
    $description            = $_POST['description'][$key];
    
    if (!empty($number)) 
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO TEST SET date=NOW(), id='$number', name='$name', description='$description'";
        $insert = $connect->query($query) or die($connect->error . __LINE__);
    }

}
?>
```

Before mysql insert i want to check that the **$number array does not contain the same numbers and zero** (like: 0,1,1,101,150).
If yes give an error to the user that the Number field need to be unique.
How can I do that the easiest way with php or javascript?
thanx ;)

Comment: compare count of array_filter + array_unique with the count of original array.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `javascript` and `html`?

Comment: [Bobby Tables: A guide to preventing SQL injection](https://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: DO you realise that `$_POST['number'][$key]` is the same as `$val`

Comment: @Andreas. Why is this tagged with javascript and html?
- How can I do that the easiest way with php or javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$arrayDuplicates = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];
$arrayNoDuplicates = [1, 2, 3, 4];

echo 'arrayDuplicates: ';
if(count($arrayDuplicates) != count(array_unique($arrayDuplicates)))
    echo 'duplicates found <br>';
else echo 'no duplicates <br>';

echo 'arrayNoDuplicates: ';
if(count($arrayNoDuplicates) != count(array_unique($arrayNoDuplicates)))
    echo 'duplicates found <br>';
else echo 'no duplicates <br>';
```

Output:

```
arrayDuplicates: duplicates found 
arrayNoDuplicates: no duplicates
```

`array_unique` is going to give you an array that contains only the unique elements.
That means, if an element has duplicates, `count(array_unique($array))` is going to be smaller than `count($array)`.

Check `array_unique` here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

**Edit:** I suggest reading other people's comments about improving your code, too.

Forgot for zero.

```
$arrayZero = [0, 1, 2, 3];
$arrayNoZero = [1, 2, 3];

echo 'arrayZero: ';
if(in_array(0, $arrayZero)) echo 'has zero. <br>';
else echo 'no zero. <br>';

echo 'arrayNoZero: ';
if(in_array(0, $arrayNoZero)) echo 'has zero. <br>';
else echo 'no zero. <br>';
```

To check if an element is in an array (if array contains 0, for example) you can use `in_array`.

Check `in_array` here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php